# Cloudformation Add Instance to Security Group in Different Region

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, jenkins, amazon-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation stack that I create through Jenkins in various Regions. I have a Chef server in one Region with a separate security group. I need new instances created via Cloudformation to register/be created and add themselves to the Chef SG in us-west-1 regardless of their region.

Is this feasible?

Edit: I need to do this via the Cloudformation script as opposed to other methods for a multitude of reasons that are lengthy/convoluted.

Edit2: For clarity, I don't want the instance to be part of the SG, but rather for that the EIP of the new instance to be added as an ingress in the SG.

Answer (score 1):

EC2/VPC Security group are region bound.

From [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

```
If you're using EC2-Classic, you must use security groups created specifically for 
EC2-Classic. When you launch an instance in EC2-Classic, you must specify a security
group in the same region as the instance. You can't specify a security group that
you created for a VPC when you launch an instance in EC2-Classic.
```

Comment: I'm not trying to use the SG in another region. I'm trying to add the EIP of $newinstance to a SG in us-west-1 as in ingress of $EIP - 443. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: You could create a script to deploy through CloudFormation and then edit your sg using EC2-CLI.

CloudFormation Commands: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/index.html

EC2-CLI Doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/Welcome.html

I don't think you can do it from the AWS Console :/

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible.

What you want is to have an security group in a security group. It work exactly how it sound.

1) Create security groups called SG-CLIENT and SG-INGRESS

2) For your CHEF instance, tag it with the SG-INGRESS security group. In the SG-INGRESS security group, add a rule to enable access to CHEF ports, using a source of 'SG-CLIENT'

3) Using cloud formation template/script, tag any new instances to the SG-CLIENT security group.

Refer to picture here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule for example of security group in rules.

Refer to https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/EC2InstanceWithSecurityGroupSample.template for registration of an instance in a security group through a cloud formation template.

Note: API documentation seems to hint toward allowing using someone else 'security group' as the source by using 'account ID/security group name'. This should be helpful if you try doing this across regions. Info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html

Comment: This is a very neat idea but doesn't seem to work between regions.

Comment: Between regions, I would simply do it with a configuration management system & deployment scripts automatically assigning IP to security group through EC2 API.